# vue.js 2 migrate from legacy frontend to single file component

Tags: javascript, components, vuejs2, legacy

So, ok, I'll get tons of downvotes for this, but since I haven't found any usable answers yet, I think it's worth a shot.

I am trying to migrate a legacy application as smoothly and as unobstrusively as  possible to vue js.

I have started with a simple component without any further children components. I am building with webpack, by the way. So, here we go. It's a simple CRUD form.

There is no vue parent context, since this is going to be the first vue-component ever in this legacy app. I've gotten this far:

```
import SinglePageVue from './single-page.vue';

// creating vue component
Vue.component('single-page-comp', SinglePageVue);

// invoke view by calling container
vue = new Vue({ el: '#component-container' });

// *** At this point I'd like to assign the data to the component
// somwhat like. Of course, this doesn't work, but this is what
// I'd like to do
vue.props.givenName = 'John'
vue.props.familyName = 'Doe'
```

and there is also a submit event, which I the calling function needs to respond to, once the form is submitted.

```
// in the script section this would look like

module.exports = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      onSubmit: function () {
        // assignable by function
      }
    }
  }
};
```

};

How do I do that?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can the data of a vue-component be reactively changed after the component has already been created?

Comment: Do you mean from outside Vue?

Comment: Yes, from outside.

I know how to set the data to a non-component vue object. But I'd like to do this with a component too. This way I could componentize the existing application bottom up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update data of a component in Vue, there are a number of ways to do it, but in this case I might suggest just creating a data object that you pass to the Vue instance, which can, again, pass it to your single page component.

```js
console.clear()

const SinglePageVue = {
  props:["sharedData"],
  template:`
    <div>
      <h1>{{sharedData.message}}</h1>
    </div>
  `
}
Vue.component("single-page-vue", SinglePageVue)

const sharedData = {
  message: "I'm shared data"
}

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    sharedData
  }
})

setTimeout(() => sharedData.message = "I was updated", 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <single-page-vue :shared-data="sharedData"></single-page-vue>
</div>
```

Here, `sharedData` is an object in your page's scope that whatever legacy code you have can modify. Because `sharedData` is exposed as a data property of the Vue, it is now reactive and changes to it's properties will be reflected anywhere they are used.

This is basically a super bare bones state management solution. If you end up needing more you might want to investigate Vuex, but I've build several Vue projects with this kind of approach.

Comment: But my entire component is encapsulated in a .vue file. At the time of creation the invoking function does not seem to have access to its data scope.

I am loading the component via:

_import SinglePageVue from './single-page.vue';_

Comment: @LongHike Some where on your page, inside `#component-container` you have `<single-page-comp></single-page-comp>`, yes?

Comment: Yes that's correct. #component-container serves as root container and <single-page-comp></single-page-comp> is currently the first component tag _living_ there. And the component does appear (it's just two input fields at the moment). But I can't pass the data to it.

Comment: @LongHike Take another look at my answer. Note that `sharedData` is passed as a property to the component. In this case, `single-page-vue` is the same thing as your `single-page-comp`. The data displayed when you run the example is only displayed by the component. When the data changes outside Vue (in the `setTimeout`), the changes are reflected *in the component*.

Comment: Bert, thanks for your efforts. I know, what you mean. And your answer is definitely right. So I will mark it as such, especially because you've explained it so well. It's not what I was hoping for, but that's my fault.

Comment: @LongHike Were you hoping to directly set values on the component?

Comment: Yes, that was my initial illusion. But then again, the more I think about it, the more it doesn't seem right.

But I must admit, that it took me a few minutes to understand your solution and also your hint to vuex. You are absolutely right right with your answer. It should actually work for the transition, since it let's me use the single file approach.